How to find the Entries Added/Removed to a particular date in PowerBi
I have a CSV file which contains the list of Groups and users from Azure, I need to find out the users who have only added for a particular date, but my CSV holds all the users in a single cell separated by semicolon.

Where's the date in this? is your structure something like (GroupName, Date, UserListCSV)? You can use PowerQuery to split the Users into distinct records by splitting on the semi-colon and then unpivoting the results.
